# Working with PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, printing, tcpdf

## Short

What I want to do is, to prepare PHP generated result for print with strong rules.

Tried all possible ways with css+html: set dimensions in px, mm, cm. 
Nothing helped. Each browser, even each printer printed absolutely different paper results (tried both with & w/o border print. also didn't get result). After long research, found that CSS is not best way for this purpose and better way - to use pdf creation functionality with PHP. So, installed TCPDF. But can't get it work with logical part that I created for HTML output.

## What I want to get

- Table's first and last rows' margin from **top and bottom** sides of paper must be **11 mm**
- Margin between rows' 0 mm
- Table's rows must be at **4 mm** from **left and right** sides of paper
- **2 mm** between every column
- **38 mm width x 21.2 mm height** each cell
- 13 x rows, 5 x columns, 13x5=65 cells
- Each table in new page. In other words - after each table **page break**
- In each cell Code 39 Barcode (value must be `$id`)
- Only tables in PDF result - no header, no footer, no title ... etc

Here is more detailed explanation on image:

[image]

## What I'm getting

After form submission, processing in php side takes too long - about minute and opens blank page instead of PDF result.

## Code:

(Code is not so huge, comments are making it look like so:)

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('John Smith');
$pdf->SetTitle(false);
$pdf->SetSubject(false);
$pdf->SetKeywords(false);

// set default header data.set all false because don't want to output header footer
$pdf->SetHeaderData(false, false, false, false);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(4, 11, 4);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// define barcode style
$style = array(
    'position' => '',
    'align' => 'C',
    'stretch' => false,
    'fitwidth' => true,
    'cellfitalign' => '',
    'border' => true,
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0, 0, 0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255),
    'text' => true,
    'font' => 'helvetica',
    'fontsize' => 8,
    'stretchtext' => 4
);

ob_start();
?>



<style type="text/css">

    table { 

        width: 100%;          

        border-collapse: collapse;

    }

    td img {
        height:10mm;
    }

    td {
        padding: 0 1mm 0 1mm;
        vertical-align:middle;              
    }

    .cell {
        width: 38mm;
        height:21mm;
        font-style: bold;
        text-align: center; 
    }

    tr    { 
        height:21mm;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;            
    }


</style>

<?php

$i = 0;
$item = new item($db);
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $id) {
    $details = $item->getDetails($id);
    $qt = (isset($_POST['qt'])) ? $_POST['qt'] : $details['qt'];
    for ($cnt = 1; $cnt <= $qt; $cnt++) {
        // check if it's the beginning of a new table
        if ($i % 65 == 0)
            echo '<table>';

        // check if it's the beginning of a new row
        if ($i % 5 == 0)
            echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td><div class="cell">www.fety.fr<br/>';
        $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 39 - ANSI MH10.8M-1983 - USD-3 - 3 of 9', 0, 1);
        $pdf->write1DBarcode($id, 'C39', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');
        $pdf->Ln();
        echo '<br/>' . $details['hcode'] . '</div></td>';

        // check if it's the end of a row
        if (($i + 1) % 5 == 0)
            echo '</tr>';

        // check if it's the end of a table
        if (($i + 1) % 65 == 0)
            echo '</tr></table>';

        $i++;
    }
}

// if the last table isn't full, print the remaining cells
if ($i % 65 != 0) {
    for ($j = $i % 65; $j < 65; $j++) {
        if ($j % 65 == 0)
            echo '<table>';
        if ($j % 5 == 0)
            echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        if (($j + 1) % 5 == 0)
            echo '</tr>';
        if (($j + 1) % 65 == 0)
            echo '</table>';
    }
}

$markup = ob_get_clean();

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($markup, true, false, true, false, '');



// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('bcsheet.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

## Script works like that:

1. User selects items' checkboxes
2. After form submission, PHP gets values of checked checkboxes via Ajax
3. In foreach loop, PHP gets quantities of each item from database.
4. Generated table

Comment: ready to give 100 rep for resolving this problem

Comment: Have you considered using raw PostScript? It is a challenging task but you'd have full control over your rendering canvas. You might also find libraries/tutorials for rendering barcodes.

Comment: @Tibo I need to output result as PDF or as HTML. HTML gives different results. So I have 1 and only way - PDF. So need to get it work

Comment: it would just take a call to ps2pdf to transform your .ps file into the final pdf.

Comment: @Tibo so what you're suggesting to do?

Comment: Browsers print HTML like my dog juggles knives: It can be deadly if you stand too close. It's not just a better way to use PDFs for print control, it's probably the only real sane, cross-platform way to do so, short of someone not having a PDF driver installed (which is infrequent these days).

Comment: As @Tibo mentions, [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) is an alternative way to create documents that provides more control but is also more "difficult" to work with than a script that takes one document type to another (HTML to PDF, for example). [PHP's Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ps.php) has a section on a PECL extension. Another option, if you can't get TCPDF to work, could be to create images and then turn them into PDFs, which might be easier to understand.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm new to TCPDF. I probably have at least one code error. So code needs to be checkeb by one who have experience with TCPDF. So if you have experience, please read the code, if it's not difficult for you. Again I'm ready to give 100 rep for resolving this problem

Comment: Well, at least superficially, I think you'd be better off not using HTML to PDF for a document you specify needs to be so accurately rendered. I say this because in TCPDF and other PDF classes, you can literally control the absolute placement of each thing you're needing by directly working with the PDF subsystem. Your HTML is still going to be interpreted in other words, but if you use [direct-write-to-cell methods](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_005.phps), you'll probably be better off. It's not as "easy", but it's also not that hard if you work at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an html/css to pdf converter library http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/

This has it's own html/css parser and thus will yield the same result in all browser.

```
<?php

$html = '
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        table {
        width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }       
        tr {

        }
        td {
            width: 38mm;
            height: 21.2mm;
            margin: 0 1mm;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align:middle; 
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++)
    {
        $html .= '<tr>';
        for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++)
        {
            $html .= '<td><barcode code="TEC-IT" type="C39" class="barcode" /></td>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }       

$html .= '</table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    include("MPDF53/mpdf.php");

    $mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4', '', '', 4, 4, 10.7, 10.7, 0, 0);

    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,0);

    $mpdf->Output('test.pdf','I');
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: TCPDF has html support too. Take a look http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_061.phps

Comment: yes but this one is more complete (it is actually built on fpdf), the only thing I could do with it in my last project was to change the opacity of a div.

Comment: One more thing in TCPDF that it support code 39 barcode.Anyway, If you have experience with pdf outputting, please help to get this work with mpdf or any pdf class that you preffer.

Comment: is there a border on those cells or is it part of the images?

Comment: the total height of your page is 297.6mm while A4 pages are 297mm

Comment: No, there is no border. I printed this just for showing. I don't need any border. But they must be at right place. For ex, if sent id's is not 65,lets say 12, they must be at first 12 cells. (Actually logic part of php - for and foreach loops did this for html.)Something like that http://i.stack.imgur.com/APcBK.png

Comment: 0.6 mm really doesn't matter :)) let it be 297

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7584/discussion-between-redmoon7777-and-epic-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you're not getting a result at all, you likely are suppressing errors in a way you can't you're getting them with your script. Also, your approach with HTML is just not how it works; you can't interleave the TCPDF native cell calls with HTML; they're not "outputting" markup. So you're mixing two different, incompatible formats, that are going to two different buffers.

However, you code should still generate a PDF.

Note the last page, with your markup-generated content.

The only changes I made was to make it where I could run it without access to your data:

```
$i = 0;
//$item = new item($db);
//foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $id) {
for ($id = 0; $id < 1; $id++) {
    //$details = $item->getDetails($id);
    //$qt = (isset($_POST['qt'])) ? $_POST['qt'] : $details['qt'];
    $details = array('These are details');
    $qt = 50;
    for ($cnt = 1; $cnt <= $qt; $cnt++) {
        // check if it's the beginning of a new table
        if ($i % 65 == 0)
            echo '<table>';

        // check if it's the beginning of a new row
        if ($i % 5 == 0)
            echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td><div class="cell">www.fety.fr<br/>';
        $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'CODE 39 - ANSI MH10.8M-1983 - USD-3 - 3 of 9', 0, 1);
        $pdf->write1DBarcode($id, 'C39', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');
        $pdf->Ln();
        echo '<br/>' . $details['hcode'] . '</div></td>';

        // check if it's the end of a row
        if (($i + 1) % 5 == 0)
            echo '</tr>';

        // check if it's the end of a table
        if (($i + 1) % 65 == 0)
            echo '</tr></table>';

        $i++;
    }
}
```

I get a PDF. It looks nothing like what you have in the image, but it does produce a PDF. I see that your code is about 90% similar to this example on the TDPDF site:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_027.phps

When I went in and made my own example, I was able to get a PDF that generally mimicked what you show in the photo. As you'll see in the code I have below, you *have* to work with the native TCPDF cell methods to get the barcode generation to work. It's not that hard; took me about 30 minutes to figure out how to produce a pdf.

The only thing I couldn't figure out was where the black line on the top comes from; it's somehow associated with the header, but I couldn't find where to turn it off. The code that's behind the second PDF:

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// define barcode style
$style = array(
    'position' => '',
    'align' => 'L',
    'stretch' => true,
    'fitwidth' => false,
    'cellfitalign' => '',
    'border' => true,
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255),
    'text' => true,
    'font' => 'helvetica',
    'fontsize' => 8,
    'stretchtext' => 4
);

for ($o = 0; $o < 5; $o++) {
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $y = 10;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
        $x = 10;

        for ($p = 0; $p < 5; $p++) {
            // UPC-E
            $pdf->write1DBarcode('04210000526', 'UPCE', $x, $y, 37, 20, 0.4, $style);

            $x = $x + 38;
        }

        $y = $y + 21;

        $pdf->Ln();
    }
}

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_027.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Comment: Thx very much. I resolved all problem with mpdf. Currently testing. If it will fail, I'll test your method.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I have the same problem with a black line appearing on top. (How) did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Connum - I never actually figured it out, I just put it up where it was hard to see it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Thanks for your reply, I managed to figure it out meanwhile! :) Just at that one line: `$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);` and it's gone! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a pdf that looks exactly like your image:

[Link to embrasse-moi.com barcode label file](http://embrasse-moi.com/exampleData/350.pdf)

AND here is the function that created it. I use tcpdf. I create 3 lines of text, the id, the description, the price, which I lookup from my sub-id, so that code you will have to replace. I also pass in the row/column offset for use with avery5167 so we can use all the stickers.

```
    function printProductLabelsAvery5167($product_sub_ids, $quantities, $row_offset, $column_offset, $filename)
{
    // Embrasse-moi.com
    require_once('../../../3rdParty/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once('../../../3rdParty/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

    $pdf_file_name = $filename;

    $subid = array();
    $poc_title = array();
    $color_price = array();

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($product_sub_ids);$i++)
    {
        $pos_product_sub_id = $product_sub_ids[$i];
        $pos_product_id = getProductIdFromProductSubId($pos_product_sub_id);
        for($qty=0;$qty<$quantities[$i];$qty++)
        {
            $subid[] = getProductSubIDName($pos_product_sub_id);
            $poc_title[] = substr(getProductTitle($pos_product_id),0,48);
            $color_price[] = substr(getProductSubIdColorDescription($pos_product_sub_id),0,38) . '     $' . number_format(getProductRetail($pos_product_id),2);
        }
    }

    $margin_left = 0;
    $margin_right = 0;
    $margin_top = 0;
    $margin_bottom = 0;
    $cell_width = 1.75;
    $cell_height = 0.5;
    $cell_spacing = 0.3;
    $columns = 4;
    $rows = 20;
    $line_spacing_adjust = 0.015;
    $barcode_spacing_adjust = 0.1;
    $barcode_height_adjust = 0.05;

    $title = 'Avery 5167 template';
    $subject = 'PO # 123';
    $keywords = 'purchase order 123';
    $page_orientation = 'P';
    $page_format = 'LETTER';
    $unit = 'in';

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF($page_orientation, $unit, $page_format, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(COMPANY_NAME);
    $pdf->SetAuthor(getUserFullName($_SESSION['pos_user_id']));
    $pdf->SetTitle($title);
    $pdf->SetSubject($subject );
    $pdf->SetKeywords($keywords);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetMargins($margin_left, $margin_top, $margin_right);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, $margin_bottom);
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    $preferences = array('PrintScaling' => 'None');
    $pdf->setViewerPreferences($preferences);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'R', 5);

    //barcode: 128a?
    // define barcode style
    $barcode_style = array(
    'position' => '',
    'align' => 'C',
    'stretch' => false,
    'fitwidth' => false,
    'cellfitalign' => '',
    'border' => false,
    'hpadding' => '0',
    'vpadding' => '0',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255),
    'text' => false,
    'font' => 'helvetica',
    'fontsize' => 4,
    'stretchtext' => 0
);


    // set border width
    $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.01);
    $pdf->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);
    //$pdf->setCellHeightRatio(3);
    $counter = 0;

    //calculating the pages.... how many labels are to be printed on the sheet...
    //how many labels are going on the first sheet?
    $first_page_number_of_spots = ($rows)*($columns-($column_offset-1)) -($row_offset-1);
    $number_of_labels = sizeof($subid);
    if($number_of_labels <= $first_page_number_of_spots)
    {
        $pages = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $lables_on_first_page = $first_page_number_of_spots;
        $labels_remaining = $number_of_labels -$lables_on_first_page;
        $number_of_spots_per_page = $rows*$columns;
        $pages = ceil($labels_remaining/($number_of_spots_per_page)) + 1;
    }
    for($page=0;$page<$pages;$page++)
    {
        $pdf->AddPage();
        for($col=$column_offset-1;$col<$columns;$col++)
        {
            for($row=$row_offset-1;$row<$rows;$row++)
            {
                if($counter< sizeof($subid))
                {
                    //barcodes must be cap
                    $line1 = strtoupper($subid[$counter]);
                    $line2 = $poc_title[$counter];
                    $line3 = $color_price[$counter];
                }
                else
                {
                    $line1 = '';
                    $line2 = '';
                    $line3 = '';
                }
                $counter++;
                $x_spot = $cell_spacing + $col*$cell_width + $col*$cell_spacing;
                $y_spot = $cell_height + $row*$cell_height;
                $coords = 'X:'.$x_spot . ' Y:' .$y_spot;
                $border = 0;
                $border2 = 0;
                //this is the cell that will allow allignment to sticker checking
                $pdf->SetXY($x_spot, $y_spot);
                $pdf->Cell($cell_width, $cell_height,  '', $border, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

                // CODE 128 A
                $pdf->SetXY($x_spot+$barcode_spacing_adjust, $y_spot);
                //cell to check the barcode placement
                $pdf->Cell($cell_width-2*$barcode_spacing_adjust, $cell_height/2, '', $border, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
                $pdf->write1DBarcode($line1, 'C128A', $x_spot+$barcode_spacing_adjust, $y_spot+$barcode_height_adjust, $cell_width-2*$barcode_spacing_adjust, $cell_height/2 - $barcode_height_adjust, 0.4, $barcode_style, 'N');

                //the remaining 3 lines have to fit in 1/2 the sticker size
                //$y_offset = $cell_height/2;
                $pdf->SetXY($x_spot, $y_spot - 0*$line_spacing_adjust + 3/6*$cell_height);
                $pdf->Cell($cell_width, $cell_height/6,  $line1, $border2, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
                $pdf->SetXY($x_spot, $y_spot - 1*$line_spacing_adjust + 4/6*$cell_height);
                $pdf->Cell($cell_width, $cell_height/6,  $line2, $border2, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
                $pdf->SetXY($x_spot, $y_spot -2*$line_spacing_adjust + 5/6*$cell_height);
                $pdf->Cell($cell_width, $cell_height/6,  $line3, $border2, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');


                //$pdf->writeHTMLCell($cell_width, $cell_height, $x_spot, $y_spot, $text_for_label, 1, 1, false, true, '', false);
                // no work $pdf->MultiCell($cell_width, $cell_height, $text_for_label, 1, 'J', false, '','',true, 0, false, true, $cell_height, 'T', false);
            }
            $row_offset = 1;
        }
        $column_offset = 1;
    }
    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output($pdf_file_name, 'D');

     //============================================================+
    // END OF FILE
    //============================================================+
    }
```