# Can't Open my Downloaded PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, download

I have a Code Below in which it Successfully downloading a .pdf file but when i open the file it always shows an error message. This is my Code:
    include("MPDF57/mpdf.php");

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list    

$html='<html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>'; //Assign HTML HERE    

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); 
$mpdf->Output('Certificate.pdf','D');
```

Please do help guys, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I already include libraries for this.

Comment: Open your file with notepad or similar text editor, it's obviously not a proper PDF file and error message will be contained within it.

Comment: `include` is for PHP scripts that should be loaded and executed. You should link to the PDF generator PHP script instead.

Comment: Also, *"an error message"* is a bit vague. Please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks for the Answers guys.Thanks to you all, i already got my answer. I just need to put this code in another page. Thanks for the idea @N.B., when i open my .pdf file it shows my html codes including the unreadable codes above that was an output in me pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

use header("Content-type:application/pdf");

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this one..will help you..**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248510/working-with-pdf-in-php
```